# Let $O$ be any point inside $\Delta ABC$. Extend $AO,BO,CO$ to meet $BC,CA,AB$ at $D,E,F$ respectively.

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> Let $O$ be any point inside $\Delta ABC$. Extend $AO,BO,CO$ to meet $BC,CA,AB$ at $D,E,F$ respectively. If $AO = 30, FO = 20, BO = 60, DO = 10, CO = 20$, find $EO$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture in Geogebra :-

[image]

The statement of the problem is really simple, every length surrounding point $O$ is given except $EO$ , which we have to find. My question is, how?

I am only given the lengths, which I don't even know how to use them. They neither help in finding lengths of other unknown lengths, nor help in angle-chasing, and so on. I don't find any similar triangles where I could have used the lengths. The only thing which I find interesting is $FO = CO$. Maybe we can use them in the areas of the triangles considering them as bases, but I can't see to find a way out there. Also that dosen't make the point $O$ special, does it, or am I missing something?

Can anyone help me or give me some hints? Thank You.

Comment: Hinty:use mass point geometry

Comment: Anything simpler which can be used, like without using mass points or barycentric coordinates and all? (I hate using them :)

Comment: I think I have found the solution using areas. I think. I think it's 20.

Comment: @player3236 yes even i got that

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I'm slightly more confident now.

Comment: You solved using areas?? How did you proceed with the areas if you cannot figure out the heights?

Comment: The areas can be in terms of other areas. For the six small triangles, I let one area be $1$ and another be $x$.

Comment: I didn't get you, are you considering the ratio of each of the areas of the triangles? How did you find it?

Comment: For example, $[\triangle AOB] : [\triangle DOB] = 3:1$. If I let $[\triangle AOF] = 3$ and $[\triangle BOF] = 3x$, then $[\triangle DOB] = 1 + x$, etc.

Comment: Also this can be solved using Melanaus theorem but we have to consider many triangles

Comment: @player3236, ok now I get it.

Comment: The *coup de grâce* (at least for what I did) is to employ a trick similar to the one used in the standard proof of Ceva's theorem.

Comment: I didn't get how I can solve using areas though, why would you,suppose, assume $[\Delta AOF] = 3$ ?

Comment: It is $3y$ after scaling. I figured I need two variables.

Comment: (od/ad) +(of/cf) +(oe/eb) =1

Comment: @endgameyourgame I don't know how I didn't think of that. Please turn this into an answer, along with the *one-line proof*.

Comment: @endgameyourgame can you tell me what theorem that is? That is a great $1$-line solution if it is true.

Comment: i dont know the name of this theorem. i found this in EGMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\triangle OBC} {\triangle ABC} =\frac{OD} {AD} , \frac{\triangle AOC} {\triangle ABC} = \frac{OE} {BE} , 
\frac{\triangle AOB} {\triangle ABC} =\frac{OF} {FC}$$
$$\frac{\triangle OBC} {\triangle ABC} + \frac{\triangle AOC} {\triangle ABC} +\frac{\triangle AOB} {\triangle ABC} = \frac{OD} {AD} +\frac{OE} {BE} +\frac{OF} {FC} =1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Apply Melanaus theorem in $\Delta ABD,\Delta CBF,\Delta ADC,\Delta AFC,\Delta CFA,\Delta BEA$

Comment: Will do it, thanks. It will take some time.

Comment: I am getting $\frac{AF}{FB} = 3, \frac{BC}{CD} = 1 , \frac{CE}{EA} = \frac{1}{3}$ , can you confirm? If this is correct, how should I go finding $EO$ then?

Comment: @Anonymous i heve edited we should apply in more triangles.This will give answer but personally it woud be better to use mass points,learn it for once and such problems become easy.

Comment: @Anonymous your answer is wrong as far as i can see $\frac{CD}{DB}=2$